# Display all data in a Table List (java spring mvc)

Tags: java, html, spring-mvc

I would like to display uploaded detail into a list, I preferred to go with any easy step in order to display all the detail. Following is my code that is only able to display one data for each time I uploaded a file. I also understand that I should make the "addObject" in the get method, not post method. How can I  display in arrayList or any other way? Any help would be appreciated!

```
This is controller 
@RequestMapping(value = "/product", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Object uploadProducts(@ModelAttribute UploadCreate uploadCreate,HttpSession session,RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {

     //   redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("list",employeeDetail.getName());
     //   redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("name",employeeDetail.getName());;

        return "product/upload";

    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/product", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "multipart/form-data")
    public Object uploadProducts(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {

        try {

            UploadCreate uploadCreate = new UploadCreate();
            uploadCreate.setName(file.getOriginalFilename());
            uploadCreate.setContentType(file.getName());
            uploadCreate.setContent(file.getBytes());
            uploadCreate.setUploadedDate(new Date());
            uploadService.uploadProducts(uploadCreate);
            return new ModelAndView("product/upload")
                    .addObject("error", "Product upload scheduled.")
                    .addObject("fileList", uploadCreate);


        } catch (Exception e) {
            return new ModelAndView("product/upload").addObject("error", e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

HTML:

```
<table id="uploaded-files">
    <tr>
        <th>File Name</th>
        <th>File Size</th>
        <th>File Type</th>
        <th>Uploaded Date</th>
    </tr>
    {{#fileList}}
    <tr>
        <td>{{name}}</td>
        <td>{{content}}</td>
        <td>{{contentType}}</td>
        <td>{{uploadedDate}}</td>
    </tr>
    {{/fileList}}
</table>
```

Comment: you want to display all uploaded files per `Session` in the `fileList` ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should use session scope instead of request scope;

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/product", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "multipart/form-data")
public Object uploadProducts(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file,HttpServletRequest request) {

    try {
        Session session = request.getSession();
        UploadCreate uploadCreate = new UploadCreate();
        uploadCreate.setName(file.getOriginalFilename());
        uploadCreate.setContentType(file.getName());
        uploadCreate.setContent(file.getBytes());
        uploadCreate.setUploadedDate(new Date());
        uploadService.uploadProducts(uploadCreate);
        List<UploadCreate> fileList =     
        (List<UploadCreate>)session.getAttribute("list");
        if(fileList==null){
          fileList = new ArrayList<UploadCreate>();
        }
        fileList.add(uploadCreate);
        session.setAttribute("list",fileList);

        return new ModelAndView("product/upload")
                .addObject("error", "Product upload scheduled.");
         //the method addObject() means to add data into request ; 
         //and the previous request and current request can not share the same data ;


    } catch (Exception e) {
        return new ModelAndView("product/upload").addObject("error", e.getMessage());
    }
}
```